# Can (range x y) be used in a Racket Dispatch: case?

Tags: racket

I would like to use a `(range x y)` in a case statement rather than listing the full range, is this possible?

I believe that the `(range 1 4)` in the second example is returning a list, and since 2 != the list, there is no match.

```
> (case 2
    [(1 2 3) "matched"]
    [else "no match"])
"matched"
> (case 2
    [(range 1 4) "matched"]
    [else "no match"])
"no match"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vanilla `case` will not work. The LHS of each branch of `case` is really limited to literals.

You can use other forms, like `cond` or `match`. E.g.,

```
(match 2
  [-1 'foo]
  [0 'bar]
  [x #:when (member x (range 1 3)) 'baz]
  [x #:when (member x (range 3 5)) 'boo])
```

This comes at the cost that it won't be as efficient as using `case`.

Another approach is to write a macro that expands to `case`, like:

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/parse/define
         (for-syntax racket/list))

(begin-for-syntax
  (define-syntax-class range-cls
    (pattern (#:range l:number r:number)
             #:with result (range (syntax-e #'l) (syntax-e #'r)))))

(define-simple-macro (case-range v [rgs:range-cls rhs ...] ...)
  (case v [rgs.result rhs ...] ...))

(case-range 2
  [(#:range -1 1) 'foo]
  [(#:range 1 3) 'bar]
  [(#:range 3 5) 'baz])
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible, because [case](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/case.html?q=case#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._case%29%29) uses *implicit quote*. In your example, it quotes all elements in list `(range 1 4)` and compares them (using [equal?](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Equality.html?q=case#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._equal%7E3f%29%29)) with 2.

```
(case 2
    [(range 1 4) "matched"]
    [else "no match"])
;2 is compared with 'range, 1, 4 => "no match"

(case 'range
    [(range 1 4) "matched"]
    [else "no match"])
;'range is compared with 'range, 1, 4 => "matched"
```

You can use [cond](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=cond#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) here:

```
(let ((v 2))
  (cond ((member v (range 1 4)) "matched 1-4")
        ((member v (range 4 8)) "matched 4-8")
        (#true "no match")))
```